# Common Gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have multiple independent microservice created using Java. We are using gradle for dependency management.

All of these projects has common dependencies like spingboot, junit etc.

I am looking for a way to create a common gradle dependency file or project which all these project can refer. So that version management is at single place.
I can't go for multimodule project.
Please suggest or share link to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are explaining the use-case for a BOM. A BOM is a collection of the software components needed to build and run a project. One of the projects you're using, Spring, makes a liberal use of BOMs to manage their own complicated dependency tree.

In this case you can make and use this list to specify the versions of all of the dependencies your microservices depend on. Then you can tell Gradle to import the BOM, and have each microservice actually request the dependencies they need without specifying a version. Gradle will use this imported BOM to resolve the version of the dependency your microservice asked for based on whats specified within the BOM.

Actually implementing this would look something like this. Currently, I assume each microservice's build.gradle looks something like:

```
// plugins, repositories, etc

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:2.1.4'
}
```

You can specify a BOM that sets a default version for each of these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        // Platform declares some versions of libraries used in subprojects
        api 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
        api 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    }
}
```

Each microservice can then request the subset of dependencies they need, import the BOM, and have the versions get resolved by the BOM.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-platform'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("your_groupid:your_bom:bom_version")
    
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'
    implementation 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient'
}
```

A couple of notes. First when you apply a BOM to a project it does not automatically bring in all of the dependencies specified in the BOM your project still needs to request what it needs, the BOM just sets default versions. Secondly, if you have 1 service that needs a different version of the dependency than the other services, that service can always override the version specified in the BOM by simply specifying the version directly in their build.gradle.

Lastly, [heres a blog post](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2019/04/gradle-goodness-use-bill-of-materials.html), by someone who is not myself, talking about using BOMs with Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found solution, posting here for other's benefits. Gradle version catalogue is meant for same scenario.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html